# Fieldsets not showing up in summary bar

Tags: html, forms, fieldset

I have created a price form. It has collapsible fieldsets that I want to show up on the pricing summary. The first fieldset shows up, however the rest will not. Am I missing something? Or do I need to delete something in my code? Please help. The site is: www.azaservice.com/mscalc.html   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other `fieldset` elements aren't showing up because they are not found inside your `form.jquery-order-form` element. Your script at the bottom of the page initializes the jPrice plugin on this form element. Move your `</form>` tag to the end of your `fieldset` elements, and I bet it starts working. Essentially, it should look something like this where all your `fieldset` elements are children of the `form` element.

```
<form class="jquery-order-form">
   <div class="options">
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">...</div>
</form>
```

**Update:** Your issues are caused by the structure of your markup. I have updated the example above to give you an idea as to how it "should" look. I have not included all of your original markup, but what's here should get you to your goal.

Here's what your complete code would probably look like:

```
<div id="main">
  <h1>AzaService Managed Services Calculator</h1>
  <form id="jquery-order-form" class="jof form-horizontal right" action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="options" style="width: 719px;">
      <fieldset id="fieldset1" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Windows Servers</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-1 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="400" value="8x5" name="f_1">
                <label for="f_1"> 8 x 5</label>
                <span class="price-tag-wrapper" style="opacity: 0;"> - <span class="price-tag">$400.00 </span></span></li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="480" value="24x7" name="f_1">
                <label for="f_1"> 24 x 7</label>
                <span class="price-tag-wrapper" style="opacity: 0;"> - <span class="price-tag">$480.00 </span></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-2 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="3" value="Antivirus" name="f_2[]">
                <label for="f_2[]"> Antivirus</label>
                <span class="price-tag-wrapper" style="opacity: 0;"> - <span class="price-tag">$3.00 </span></span></li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="50" value="Onsite" name="f_2[]">
                <label for="f_2[]"> Onsite</label>
                <span class="price-tag-wrapper" style="opacity: 0;"> - <span class="price-tag">$50.00 </span></span></li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="20" value="Backup" name="f_2[]">
                <label for="f_2[]"> Backup</label>
                <span class="price-tag-wrapper" style="opacity: 0;"> - <span class="price-tag">$20.00 </span></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Windows Servers: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_1" id="q_1" value="1" data-quantity="f_1,f_2[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset2" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Linux Servers</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-3 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="400" value="8x5" name="f_3[]">
                <label for="f_3[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="480" value="24x7" name="f_3[]">
                <label for="f_3[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-4 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="3" value="Antivirus" name="f_4[]">
                <label for="f_4[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="50" value="Onsite" name="f_4[]">
                <label for="f_4[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="20" value="Backup" name="f_4[]">
                <label for="f_4[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Linux Servers: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_2" id="q_2" value="2" data-quantity="f_3[],f_4[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset3" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Unix Servers</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-5 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="400" value="8x5" name="f_5[]">
                <label for="f_5[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="480" value="24x7" name="f_5[]">
                <label for="f_5[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-6 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="3" value="Antivirus" name="f_6[]">
                <label for="f_6[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="50" value="Onsite" name="f_6[]">
                <label for="f_6[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="20" value="Backup" name="f_6[]">
                <label for="f_6[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Unix Servers: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_3" id="q_3" value="3" data-quantity="f_5[],f_6[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset4" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Windows Workstations</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-7 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="55" value="8x5" name="f_7[]">
                <label for="f_7[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="66" value="24x7" name="f_7[]">
                <label for="f_7[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-8 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" value="Antivirus" name="f_8[]">
                <label for="f_8[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="10" value="Onsite" name="f_8[]">
                <label for="f_8[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="5" value="Backup" name="f_8[]">
                <label for="f_8[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Windows Workstations: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_4" id="q_4" value="4" data-quantity="f_7[],f_8[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset5" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Linux Workstations</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-9 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="55" value="8x5" name="f_9[]">
                <label for="f_9[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="66" value="24x7" name="f_9[]">
                <label for="f_9[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-10 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" value="Antivirus" name="f_10[]">
                <label for="f_10[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="10" value="Onsite" name="f_10[]">
                <label for="f_10[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="5" value="Backup" name="f_10[]">
                <label for="f_10[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Linux Workstations: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_5" id="q_5" value="5" data-quantity="f_9[],f_10[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset6" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Unix Workstations</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-11 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="55" value="8x5" name="f_11[]">
                <label for="f_11[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="66" value="24x7" name="f_11[]">
                <label for="f_11[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-12 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="2" value="Antivirus" name="f_12[]">
                <label for="f_12[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="10" value="Onsite" name="f_12[]">
                <label for="f_12[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="5" value="Backup" name="f_12[]">
                <label for="f_12[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Unix Workstations: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_6" id="q_6" value="6" data-quantity="f_11[],f_12[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset7" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Mobile Units</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-13 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="40" value="8x5" name="f_13[]">
                <label for="f_13[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="48" value="24x7" name="f_13[]">
                <label for="f_13[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-14 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="50" value="Antivirus" name="f_14[]">
                <label for="f_14[]"> Antivirus</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="50" value="Backup" name="f_14[]">
                <label for="f_14[]"> Backup</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Mobile Units: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_7" id="q_7" value="7" data-quantity="f_13[],f_14[]">
      </label>
      <fieldset id="fieldset8" class="coolfieldset collapsed">
        <legend>Networks</legend>
        <div class="sub-option o-15 o-radio" data-type="radio" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Service Level: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" data-cost="30" value="8x5" name="f_15[]">
                <label for="f_15[]"> 8 x 5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" data-cost="36" value="24x7" name="f_15[]">
                <label for="f_15[]"> 24 x 7</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-option o-10 o-checkbox" data-type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
          <div class="well" style="display: none;">
            <p><strong>Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-cost="50" value="Onsite" name="f_16[]">
                <label for="f_16[]"> Onsite</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <label><strong>Number of Networks: </strong>
        <input type="number" name="q_8" id="q_8" value="8" data-quantity="f_15[],f_16[]">
      </label>
      <p>
        <input class="submit btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Send it Off!">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <div class="total well">
        <h3>Total: <span class="price">$4939.00 </span></h3>
        <input type="hidden" id="total-cost" name="total-cost" value="4939">
      </div>
      <div class="summary well">
        <h3>Summary:</h3>
        <div class="itemized-summary">
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Windows Server Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Windows Server Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Windows Servers: </strong>1</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Linux Server Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Linux Server Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Linux Servers: </strong>2</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Unix Server Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Unix Server Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Unix Servers: </strong>2</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Windows Workstation Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Windows Workstation Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Windows Workstations: </strong>4</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Linux Workstation Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Linux Workstation Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Linux Workstations: </strong>5</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Unix Workstation Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Unix Workstation Services: </strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Onsite</li>
              <li>Backup</li>
            </ul>
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Unix Workstations: </strong>6</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Mobile Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Mobile Services: </strong>Backup</p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Mobile Units: </strong>7</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="line-item">
            <p><strong>Network Service Level: </strong>24x7</p>
          </div>
          <div class="quantity">
            <p><strong>Number of Networks: </strong>8</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Which tag should I move? I moved 
<form id="jquery-order-form" class="jof form-horizontal" action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> to the bottom but it only deleted the pricing summary.

Comment: I'm sorry...I forgot to mark the tag as "code", so it wasn't displaying in the response. Your opening `<form>` tag was fine, so put it back where you had it.

Comment: did that fix your issue?

Comment: Thank you for replying. However it did not fix it. My </form> is at the end of my last </fieldset>. Whenever I change where my form placement is the summary bar on the right hand side doesn't show up.

Comment: Everything was working till I added collapsible fieldsets into the mix. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to do this. I will apply your changes and hopefully it fixes it.

Comment: If it does, remember to come back and mark this as the accepted answer. Makes people more willing to help you in the future. Another suggestion is to include your code that is problematic instead of simply supplying a link to the page. Not everyone likes navigating to random pages on the web.

Comment: It worked! Thanks again for your help and future advice.

Comment: Good to hear. Happy coding!